# Finding the number of elements in an array to be replaced by a given number such that the sum of the array is smaller than another given number

Tags: python, arrays

I need help with a certain problem.Suppose you are given a sorted array "A", which has "N" elements and two integers "X" and "Y". Now you are asked two find the number of elements in "A" you have to replace with "X" such that the sum of the array "A" is less than "Y". The given problem can be easily solved in O(n^2) using the following technique.(Only the code snippet for this is specific operation).

```
sum = None
count = None
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(i):
        A[j] = X
        count += 1
   for k in range(N):
        sum += A[k]
   if sum==Y:
        print(count)
        count = 0
        break
```

But I want to do this in a more efficient way,can someone suggest a more efficient way?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient?

Comment: I want to know if this is possible in O(n) time or O(n log n) time

Comment: `for k in range(N): sum += A[k]` does not seem right, as it is executed each time without resetting sum and sum is initialized to be none before the first loop

Comment: I will just keep sum = 0 to fix that , hopefully that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your array is sorted you can:

1. calculate the sum of your array (O(n))
2. check if saved_sum<=Y is satisfied (O(1))
3. Start at the last/first position (depending on where the largest value is)

   3.1 check if that value is larger than X, if not it's not possible to reduce the sum of A any further

   3.2 replace by X and decrease saved_sum by value-x

   3.3 check if saved_sum <= Y, if not repeat at 3.1 with 2nd largest value in A

Whole thing runs in O(n) since A is sorted and largest/next largest can be found in O(1)